# how does ssh discover hostnames on the network?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, openssh

We have a server on the company network named serverA, and if I type `ssh serverA`, it will connect my PC to this server, even though there is no entry for this server in my `/etc/hosts`, but I used to have another PC where I do have to set this up manually in `/etc/hosts`. So, how does ssh discover hostnames on the network, and how can I make sure it works? (Both these machines I mentioned are running Kubuntu Linux, the older one runs 12.10, the newer one runs 13.04.)

I have the following content in `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search mycompany.com
```

Processes listening on port 53:

```
sudo ss -ulnp | grep 53
#UNCONN     0      0                         *:5353                     *:*      users:(("avahi-daemon",937,12))
#UNCONN     0      0                 127.0.1.1:53                       *:*      users:(("dnsmasq",1781,4))
#UNCONN     0      0                        :::5353                    :::*      users:(("avahi-daemon",937,13))
```

Comment: Does you network have a DNS server? Does it have an entry for serverA ?

Comment: @Hennes I don't really know, but I have posted the resolve.conf above, could you have a look? Thanks.

Comment: You have this line `nameserver 127.0.1.1` which tells the resolver to try to translate hostnames to IP addresses. The IP of the nameserver starts with 127, and 127/8 points back to your own host. So you probably are running a nameserver on your own computer.

Comment: What process is listening locally on your box on port 53? `sudo ss -ulnp | grep 53`

Comment: @mindthemonkey Please see the edited post.

Comment: @CravingSpirit ok, `grep nameserver /etc/dnsmasq.conf` and `ps -ef | grep dnsmasq` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when the server is within the DNS search domain you have configured.

For example, my current search domain is example.com:

```
$ grep ^search /etc/resolv.conf
search example.com
```

I can now do the following transparently:

```
$ ping foo.example.com
PING foo.example.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
$ ping foo
PING foo.example.com (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
```

Search domains allow automatic translation between the machine's name and the fully qualified domain name (FQDN).

Comment: My resolve.conf has a line `search example.com`, so what's the difference between `search` and `domain`?

Comment: Just a note, `domain example.com` configures the local domain which the search domain defaults to. The search domain can additionally be configured with `search example.com someextradomain.com`

Answer (score 3):

The OpenSSH client uses the standard [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) resolver provided by your operating system to resolve host names to an IP address.

The `hosts` config in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nsswitch.conf) configures what should be looked at to resolve hosts and and in what order.

Normally most lookups will be completed by the `dns` resolver which is configured in [`/etc/resolv.conf`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf). 
You probably need to contact the person who administers the `nameserver` noted in `/etc/resolv.conf` and ask them to configure the hostname/IP for you, which in your case of 127.0.1.1 appears to be yourself. If you have a dynamic DHCP IP address this might not be possible depending on your setup.

If `mdns` or Multicast DNS is what enables your working host, your new host might be on a different subnet or not broadcasting it's name.